# Don't want Redirect 301 to affect subfolder in /public_html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this rule in .htaccess:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php https://newdomain.com/
```

But I still want to use a folder at olddomain.com ... e.g., I want to visit `olddomain.com/subfolder/` but instead I'm getting redirected to `newdomain.com/subfolder/`, which doesn't exist of course.

I've also tried this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^subfolder($|/) https://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

(as suggested here: https://www.fdgweb.com/exclude-sub-directory-htaccess-301-redirects/), but it didn't work either.

Is there a way to have a subfolder as an exception to the 301 redirect? Or, instead, is there a way to have the 301 redirect only apply to the folder the .htaccess file is in?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the redirect to apply only to /index.php, which means i can still access olddomain/subfolder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddoman\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Sectigo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "https\:\/\/newdomain\.com\/" [R=302,L]
```